# How can I run SASS in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2, css

I downloaded this [SASS syntax highlighting files](https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass) and done the four steps instructed (as a Mac user). But I don't know how to run it so that my .sass file is converted to .css

Can you suggest me anything?

Comment: I've given up on Sublime Text, everything needs to installed and configured, etc. Try using Aptana Studio3, compiling sass file is no-brainer just press crt+shift+r and it's done!

Comment: Refer to this https://www.codesmite.com/article/building-sass-and-scss-in-sublime-text#:~:text=INSTALLING%20WITH%20SUBLIME%20PACKAGE%20CONTROL&text=When%20the%20list%20of%20available,package%20will%20now%20install%20automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out **[Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/)**. Run a `compass watch` and never look back.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Edge with Sublime Text 2 to live edit Sass & Compass files. Check it out here http://getedge.io

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that uses Sublime's Build system to do the conversion. In Sublime, open "Tools > Build System" and choose Automatic, then try building (Cmd+B, F7, or Tools>Build.) If it still doesn't work, try changing the Build System from Automatic to SASS.

Answer (score 0):

I use [hammer for mac](http://hammerformac.com/) which has built in support for compiling SASS, coffeescript, HAML among others, as well as loads of other great features such as non-PHP includes, clever paths, variables etc.

Highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how different things will be on Mac, but I use Sublime Text 2 on both Windows and Linux without any issues regarding Sass. I haven't used the plugin [sublime-text-haml-sass](https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass) though.

I would say:

1. Make sure Sass is installed on your system. The instructions for that plugin don't    cover that. *Make sure that Sass works outside Sublime*. This has been a requirement for the plugins I've used for Sass processing.
2. Select the correct **Build System**. For me, sometimes the **Automatic**
   option does not work. I would advise you to select it manually. The
   [Compass](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Compass) and [SASS Build](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SASS%20Build) plugins add Compass and SASS
   options respectively, to that **Tools >> Build System** menu. I would
   guess that [sublime-text-haml-sass](https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass) does the same.
3. Remember to run the build (via **Tools >> Build** manually).

Answer (score 0):

[CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) works like a charm;
Simply open up your Sass/HTML/JS in Sublime Text, then run CodeKit.

Drag and drop your source folder into CodeKit, hit Preview and voila – it compiles and update all changes while giving you a live preview.